# Is that possible to do a s/mime sign in browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, browserify, smime

I am not very familiar with PKI, so allow me to ask a question:

Suppose I have following shell script,

```
openssl smime -sign -outform DER -md sha512 -binary -signer <somefile> -inkey <somefile> -in <message> -out outfile
```

Is it possible to do the same job in browser?(I mean using pure js, there is no way to run shell in browser) Is there any good library I can check?

I already checked [PKI.js](https://pkijs.org/) ,and [node smime module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smime) with browserify, I think both of them can not do it.

If there is no good library for it, is there any alternative way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: From the description, I would expect PKI.js can do it. What makes you think it does not?

Comment: @not2savvy I am not very familiar with pki and sign algorithm, could u explain more about it?

Comment: I'm not too familiar either, but I would start with PKI.js as seen in the examples on their web site. Did you do so? If so, help us understand what it was that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is the command I used to generate a message PKI.js was able to verify:

`openssl cms -in test2.txt -signer cmssign.txt -sign -nodetach -outform PEM > sslcmssign.pem`

You can test it out [here](https://pkijs.org/examples/CMSSigned_complex_example.html)

The parse field wants just the binary, so you'll need to process the CMS files like this:

`sed '/CMS/d' sslcmssign.pem | base64 -d > sslcmssign.bin`

Comment: You might need to write your own MIME header parser, but PKI.js can take care of verifying the signature and unpacking an opaque signature.